# AWS Workmail won't verify domain

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, email-validation, records, amazon-workmail

So I'm setting up my domain and have gotten the DNS to route to the page without a problem. But now when I try to verify the domain through AWS Workmail, the domain status is constantly "Pending Verification."

For those of you who don't know, Amazon makes you add a TXT record type to your DNS to perform this verification. Sounds simple enough right?

So I did that, and nothing, still stuck. Waited a day(close to two) just incase the DNS was being funky and needed some time to catch up, still nothing.

To make this even weirder, I can see the TXT record fine by running `nslookup` on any of the domain's nameservers.

Is AWS Workmail looking in a weird spot for this?
I could really use any guidance.

**Some important notes:**

The DNS is Route 53. 
The domain was purchased through AWS.

You can access the webpage fine by just typing in the url.

The whole website was pretty much setup by Amazon's quick start service for static websites. Seems to have worked flawlessly, as I did it manually at first and was encountering the same problem(close to a week ago).

Comment: Check with their customer support

Comment: First verify the text record you set for the domain match with that provided by AWS for verification.

Comment: Show the results of your nslookup, obfuscating your domain name if necessary, but not the rest, please.

Comment: The result of "nslookup -type=TXT" is literally as it should be according to amazon so I'm completely confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently nothing was wrong. The DNS just took 4 days to update it's data. Not sure what went wrong to prompt this but oh well.

Comment: :( Guess I'm in it for the long haul. Thanks for letting me know that this type of wait isn't unusual.

Comment: :( #metoo.. why 4 days.. !!

Answer (score 0):

Add the TXT type record to your Route 53 Hosted Zone for the domain. It should verify you pretty instantly.

My domain was registered with DirectNic and I initially added the TXT record over there.